# MySQL Query Using LEFT JOIN Hangs

Tags: mysql

Can somebody please advise where I could be going wrong with the following query which is causing my page to hang:

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.member_name, SUM(CONCAT(f.pounds, '.', f.pence)) AS totalfigure
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN figures f ON f.member_id = m.member_id AND f.period_id = 45
WHERE m.added BETWEEN '1980-01-01' AND '2014-10-31'
AND (DATE_SUB('2014-08-01', INTERVAL 60 DAY)) < m.removed
GROUP BY m.member_id
ORDER BY m.member_name;
```

The same query runs fine if I use JOIN rather than LEFT JOIN but I need to also view members that do not have an entry in the figures table.

This is the EXPLAIN result I get with the LEFT JOIN:

```
id   select_type   table   type   possible_keys   key   key_len   ref   rows   Extra
 1   SIMPLE        m       ALL    NULL            NULL  NULL      NULL  3128   Using temporary; Using filesort
 1   SIMPLE        f       ALL    NULL            NULL  NULL      NULL  169214
```

and with the JOIN the result is:

```
id   select_type   table   type   possible_keys   key     key_len   ref             rows    Extra
 1   SIMPLE        f       ALL    NULL            NULL    NULL      NULL            169214  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
 1   SIMPLE        m       eq_ref PRIMARY         PRIMARY 3         db.f.member_id  1
```

The structure for each of these tables is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
`member_id` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`member_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `member_name` (`member_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3462 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `figures` (
`supplier_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`contract_id` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`member_id` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`period_id` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`pounds` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`pence` char(3) DEFAULT '00',
PRIMARY KEY (`supplier_id`,`member_id`,`period_id`,`contract_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not have separate indexes on memebe_rid  and period_id on teh figures table.? A composite PK is not usually a useful index for anythign except the first field in SQL Server. mysql may have the same problems.  Of course thw left join will alawys  take longer because there are more records being returned. However, if you improve the indexing, it may not get hung up.

Comment: I might also consider this part: (DATE_SUB('2014-08-01', INTERVAL 60 DAY)) If you can calcuate that outside of the select, it could speed things up considerably.  At least it could in SQl Server. Read about creating saragble queries for mysql.

Comment: Why do you store pounds and pence as CHAR/VARCHAR and why in different fields?

Comment: have you tried moving "AND f.period_id = 45" out of the join statement and into the where clause?

Comment: Thanks all for taking the time to answer. I think the issue is now resolved thanks to @HLGEM. I added a new index to the figures table for member_id alone and it is no longer hanging.

Comment: Just make sure you fix the where issue too or you will have incorrect results.